# Finite Difference Spacing of Points for PDE's for Convergence of Explicit Forward-Stepping Scheme

Tags: partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, finite-differences

I realize that this question could be pretty broad, but I'm wondering at least what the conditions are for my simulation.

I'm developing an Explicit Forward-Stepping Finite Difference scheme to solve a nonlinear, time-dependent, heat flow (thermal diffusion) equation in cylindrical symmetry.  As such, I am interested in the temperature as a function of time t, radius R, and axial position Z (no $\theta$ dependence).

In my case, the radius is larger than the thickness (R >> Z), roughly 10 to 1.

My question is this:  when deciding the spacing (or stencil?) between points/nodes for my simulation, is it better to:

(1)  Use the same ***number*** of points in each spatial dimension (say, 100 in R, and 100 in Z)?

or,

(2)  Use the same ***ratio*** of points at the ratio of the spatial dimensions (say, 20 in R and 2 in Z, i.e. 10 to 1)?

As I said, I'd like to know the proper way to do it for general cases, but knowing for my case would be helpful by itself.

Also, does the time step also need to obey some equality in comparison to the spacing in R and Z at the same time?  I've seen conditions for convergence, but those appear to be some ratio between time and one spatial dimension, not time and all spatial dimensions.  Thanks!

Comment: The main focus is the dimensions of the physical problem you are trying to solve. For example in plasma physics solving MHD equations in a flux tube (cylinder) we had characteristics of the wave propagation such Alfvin speed and magnetoacoustic speed properties which depended on the direction of the magnetic field. What I am trying to say, is the physics you are trying to model dictates the grid size as use isotropic grids will be to fine for the model or worse still doesn't capture the scales you want :).

Comment: @Chinny84 Thank you for your comment, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "the physics you are trying to model".  As I said, I am doing thermal diffusion/heat flow modeling of a nonlinear system; I want to know the temperature distribution and evolution given the initial and boundary conditions.  Is there something else that I should specify in order to determine what spacing I need to use?  Please let me know either way, and thanks!

Comment: No worries. What I meant was, if thermal diffusion coefficent is not isotropic (uniform in all directions) then having the same step stencil in all directions is over kill :). So if thermal diffusion is more rapid (or varies spatially a great deal) along the z axis as opposed to radially then you have to have a finer spatial step to capture the dynamics. However looking at your problem, it seems that you are solving a problem where the z axis is treated as closed and I have no prior experience of that (only "infinite" length) contd

Comment: ..so I suggest playing around with the setup and see how it turns out and take care with stability conditions. I think someone with more numerical experience will come along in no time on here (or the physics equivalent if you post it there). Good luck

Comment: I recommend the site [scicomp.se]

Comment: @thisismuchbetter I thought we weren't supposed to double post a question.  Should I request to have it moved, or have another user submit it as theirs?  What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: @thisismuchbetter Also, there seem to be far more finite-difference related question on this site rather than Computational Science.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is (IMHO), that it is more important that the ***spacing*** (or in your case, or ratio of points) be equal in each dimension.  That is to say, for your problem, that dr = dz, otherwise, diffusion will occur at different rates in different directions, leading to "false diffusion".  I don't have a source or reference for this.  So if R>>Z (R:Z = 10:1), then for dr to equal dz, you would need 10 times as many points in the r-direction than the z-direction.  For Cartesian this is more straight forward because the size of your cells remains constant if you take this approach, however with cylindrical (and spherical ?), it is a little more difficult to see.

If someone else wants to weigh in on this and/or has a proof or reference, I'd like to know!